# Some files or parts of code Apache 2.0 into new Open Source project

Tags: apache-2.0, license

If one is to release a new open source project using a license like Apache 2.0 or MIT, or any other, and this project uses some files or parts of code, that can be slight modified for a proper use or as they are, how to specify the license attribution?

Let's suppose there is the following code structure

- File 1
- **File 2**
- **File 3**
- File 4
- ... over other 20 files

But File 2 is all my code, except one or two lines of that project code
File 3 is fully code from the other project, with possible small changes to adapt to my project

Should I post the full license of the Apache project on the beginning of File 3?

What about File 2? How to indicate that part of the code has another license?

Comment: It depends on the requirements of the licence on File 2.  What licence is it under?

Comment: The code from another project is Apache 2.0